# Java generic issue: "incompatible types; inferred type argument(s) java.lang.Object do not conform to bounds of type variable(s) T

Tags: java, generics, types

The following simple program compiles with Eclipse compiler, but not Javac:

```
public class Test {

    public static interface Function<T1, T2, Boolean> {
        Boolean apply(T1 t1, T2 t2);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> Function<T, T, Boolean> _cmp(final boolean lt) {
        return new Function<T, T, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(T t1, T t2) {
                if (lt) {
                    return (t1.compareTo(t2) < 0);
                } else {
                    return (t1.compareTo(t2) > 0);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static Function LESS_THAN = _cmp(true); // error line
    public static Function GREATER_THAN = _cmp(false); // error line

}
```

The error message of Javac:

```
java: P:\java-tool\src\main\java\T3.java:20: incompatible types; inferred type argument(s) java.lang.Object do not conform to bounds of type variable(s) T
found   : <T>T3.Function<T,T,java.lang.Boolean>
required: T3.Function
```

Comment: What `javac` version?

Comment: I don't understand why you a type parameter named `Boolean`.

Comment: Compiles fine for me with `javac 1.7.0_45`.

Comment: @BheshGurung is probably on to something.  My eclipse gave me a warning on that, and I removed Boolean from the type params.  Everything compiled at taht point

Comment: In Idea with `jdk7` also compiled normally.

Comment: @Gus That won't cause a compilation error as you are not trying to use `Boolean` as a type anywhere in the code. Its use as a type variable is simply obscuring the type.

Comment: But the problem is in `T3.java` class! Where is it?

Comment: Please ignore the T3, I renamed the file to Test makes it easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type inference is not working for version 1.6 -

Try manually specifying the type argument. E.g. -

```
public static Function LESS_THAN = Test.<Integer>_cmp(true); // error line
```

Note that you are using the raw version of your own generic class there.