# Intellij is giving strange error. Java Generics issue

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I want to produce an object from a string, I also want that produced object to be of type IObjectImpl that extends IObject.

So, I have a factory class method that takes a string and an interface class(say IObjectImpl.class that extends IObject, which is mandatory). That method should automatically detect that the object produced from string(using reflection) type is IObject and cast it to IObjectImpl.

I have written the following code for testing. But, Intellij does not show error and at the same time while I run the main method, I get the error shown at the end.

```
public <T extends IObject, E extends T> E getInstanceOfType(String clazz, Class type) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Type got is " + type);
        return null;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new ObjectInstantiationException(String.format("Could not create the "
                + "instance of type %s", clazz), exception);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Factory().getInstanceOfType("Some class", IObjectImpl.class);
}
```

The error is:

```
    Error:(67, 49) java: ..path\Factory.java:67: incompatible types; inferred type argument(s) com.myCompany.IObject,java.lang.Object do not conform to bounds of type variable(s) T,E
found   : <T,E>E
required: java.lang.Object
```

As far as checking type, I just know about eClass.isAssignableFrom(tClass) approach.

My final goal is that I should be able to call the methods defined in `IObjectImpl` without any cast. How can I do it using Java 1.6?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893223/java-generic-issue-incompatible-types-inferred-type-arguments-java-lang-obj

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the generic bound on `Class`? And perhaps you're getting a warning about raw types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the types like this: (java 6)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Factory().<IObject, IObjectImpl> getInstanceOfType("Some class", IObjectImpl.class);
}
```

Comment: It works in a stand alone way. Can I wire the same factory as a bean and get somewhere else using spring?

Comment: Thank you. By providing the generic on Class  like Class<E> there is no problem. I think spring can also wire.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Factory {
    public <T extends IObject, E extends T> E getInstanceOfType(String clazz, Class<E> type) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Type got is " + type);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not create the "
                    + "instance of type %s", clazz), exception);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Factory().<IObject, IObjectImpl>getInstanceOfType("Some class", IObjectImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice copy of an answered that was posted 6 minutes before yours :)

Comment: No worries. For future - see the top of the page. If it says "A new answer to this question has been posted", click to refresh before posting your own answer. This will help to avoid duplicates :)